# jQuery common functionality in file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a C#.NET MVC3 web app and I have some common jQuery functionality across my pages and want to modularize it. I don't know how to do this. Below is an example of the code I'm using. You will notice several controls have functions assigned to events. Each View I have will do this, BUT the controls (and number of controls) will be different. There may be 1 control that needs the event added to or there may be 10.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", minDate: "12/27/2011" }); 

    $("#Description").keyup(function () {
        enableSaveAlert();
    });
    $("#DueDate").change(function () {
        enableSaveAlert();
    });
    $("#DueDate").keyup(function () {
        enableSaveAlert();
    });
});


    function enableSaveAlert() {
        document.title = document.title.replace("*", "");
        document.title = document.title + "*";
        return true;
    }
```

Any ideas how to put this into one .js file?

Comment: How is that code NOT in one .js file? Do you have the example you posted copied and pasted into each of your view files?

Comment: @Terminal...yes, that code is in each of my Views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having an Id selector per input element, why not put a class on all the elements which require the `enableSaveAlert()` function to be called on them?

So in your HTML you'd have

```
<input type="text" name="Description" class="save-alert" />
<input type="text" name="DueDate" class="save-alert" />
<input type="text" name="OtherField" />
```

Then in your JS, attach your events once via that class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", minDate: "12/27/2011" }); 

    $(".save-alert").bind("change keyup", function() {
        enableSaveAlert();
    });
});

function enableSaveAlert() {
    document.title = document.title.replace("*", "");
    document.title = document.title + "*";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Rory....the individual controls already have their own classes.  So, they need to be seperate.  And one question, wouldn't this code go in the .js file? $(".save-alert").bind("change keyup", function() {     enableSaveAlert(); });

Comment: Are you unable to add a new class to each control? And you're right it should be JS - that was a typo :)

Comment: @Rory...what do you mean....can't a control only have one class?  I don't understand

Comment: Elements in HTML can have as many classes as you need. They may only have 1 Id.

Comment: @Rory...cool.  How do you declare the classe in  html?  class="class1, save-alert" ?

Comment: Just with a space in between them, so `<input class="class-1 class-2 class-n" />`

Comment: OK...I'll check that.  I still want this code in one js file.  That's cleaner I think

Comment: @Rory....thanks again. That works nicely. I put most of the js code in a js file: function SetSaveAlert() { $(".save-alert").bind("change keyup", function () { enableSaveAlert(); }); } function enableSaveAlert() { document.title = document.title.replace("*", ""); document.title = document.title + "*"; return true; }

Comment: And then called SetSaveAlert() in all my views.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting your `$(document).ready` function in one file called main.js and then include that file in the head of your template view.

So in your index or layout template view you'd have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
...
```

I think it's always a good idea to keep ALL Javascript in well-organized .js files and never in any of the individual views.